# Python - How can I find out if a specific XML node is present using Python?

Tags: python

Here is a sample of some XML code I have:

```
<VAST version="2.0">
<Ad id="602678">
<InLine>
<AdSystem>Acudeo Compatible</AdSystem>
<AdTitle>NonLinear Test Campaign 1</AdTitle>
<Description>NonLinear Test Campaign 1</Description>
<Creatives>
<Creative AdID="602678-NonLinear">
</Creative>
</Creatives>
</InLine>
</Ad>
</VAST>
```

This XML is served online so I hit a specific URL in order to get this data back. However, in some cases, nothing is returned so I am looking for a way to verify whether or not the "Creatives" node is present in whatever is returned at any given time. I have tried BeautifulSoup with no luck but I think that is more for HTML rather than XML. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with plain-text checking? i.e. `if "<Creatives>" in your_returned_payload: ...`

Comment: I think the trouble I am having is with parsing the XML data itself after trying to pull it from the web URL I am hitting. I will update by POST with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you retrieve the XML from an URL like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    xml_tag_exists(r)
```

Then you just have to build a simple function which will return `True`/`False` based on whether the required XML tag exists:

```
def xml_tag_exists(r):
    return '<Creatives>' in r.text
```

For example, let's take the [following URL](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml):

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> if r.status_code == 200:
...     print(r.text)
```

The above will return an XML of the following form:

> ```
> <CATALOG>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   <PLANT>
>     <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
>     <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
>     <ZONE>3</ZONE>
>     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
>     <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
>     <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
>   </PLANT>
>   ...
> </CATALOG>
> ```

Which if we check for some tag:

```
>>> if '<CATALOG>' in r.text:
...     print(True)
...
True
```

So, if I were to do this, I'd write something like this:

```
import requests


def xml_tag_exists(r):
    return '<Creatives>' in r.text


def main():
    r = requests.get('your_url_goes_here')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        xml_tag_exists(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That will work only if the returned content is only "<Creatives>" and nothing else.

Comment: @zwer it was just a typo. It was meant to be `"<Creatives>" in r.text`. Thanks for head-ups. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

```
from lxml import etree

f = StringIO(YOURS_XML)
tree = etree.parse(f)

creatives_node = tree.xpath('/Creatives')
```